# Shiny: uiOutput vs plugging reactive values to selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I need to generate choices for selectInput on the server side (they will change based on the changes in the database). Is there any other option than rendering the whole UI element on the server side, as in this example?

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data("mtcars")
  output$select_cars = renderUI({
    selectInput("cyl",
                label = "Select cylinder",
                choices = mtcars %>% distinct(cyl) %>% pull %>% append("All", after = 0))
  })
}

ui = fluidPage(
  uiOutput("select_cars")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Something akin of creating reactive values on the server side and sending them to UI to render? If so, what is more advisable practice (or what are the pros and cons)?

Comment: Another option that comes to my mind is to use updateSelectInput on the start of the app. Thoughts?

Comment: Good summary of available options at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html, but here indeed, and whenever it does the trick, `update*Input()` is preferable. It gives code that is clearer and easier to reason about

Comment: do you have some reproducible example with update*Input()? I tried using code from [link](https://shiny.oxshef.io/tutorials_controls-dependent-on-data.html) but it does not work

Comment: `example("updateSelectInput", package = "shiny")` could do, and reading `help(updateSelectInput)`, also see my answer for another example (and for achieving "select all" in a nicer way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of using `updateSelectInput`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  selectInput("column", "Select column", choices = names(mtcars)),
  selectInput("value", "", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$column, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "value", paste("Select", input$column, "value(s)"),
                      choices = sort(unique(mtcars[[input$column]])))
  })

  output$selected <- renderText({
    paste0(input$column, ": ", paste(input$value, collapse = ", "))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Also, not OP's question, but we can see they're trying to achieve a "select all" option, I would suggest `shinyWidgets::pickerInput()` that has (a nice implementation of) this feature out of the box:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  selectInput("column", "Select column", choices = names(mtcars)),
  pickerInput("value", "", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, 
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$column, {
    updatePickerInput(session, "value", paste("Select", input$column, "value(s)"),
                      choices = sort(unique(mtcars[[input$column]])))
  })

  output$selected <- renderText({
    paste0(input$column, ": ", paste(input$value, collapse = ", "))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Example that more closely mimicks OP:

```
ui <-  fluidPage(
  pickerInput("cyl", "", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, 
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updatePickerInput(session, "cyl", "Select cylinder", 
                      choices = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

which can even be simplified further if reactivity is not needed to update the input:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  updatePickerInput(session, "cyl", "Select cylinder", 
                    choices = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pickerInput() example. Looks quite useful. Regarding the solution using observeEvent - I need to get the selection filled at the start of the app - not based on some additional interaction with the app. I was able to achieve this by renderUI, but I wondered, whether is it the best solution.

Comment: In my example, the selection _is_ "filled" at app startup. See edit to my answer for another example that more closely mimicks your original question, and that fills in at startup too

Comment: I must be utterly missing something here, but all the examples need some user input first. The only thing I wanted was to collect the values, (that can change from session to session, but won't change during the session) and send them to ui. I guess I need to take a brake and look at it with a fresh mind. Thanks!

Comment: User input is not needed. I've simplified further the last example to demonstrate it. Have you tried to run it?

Comment: perfect! thank you very much for your help! I kinda spent yesterday to comprehend it all.